# OutOfMemoryError what to increase and how?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a really long collection with 10k items, and when running a toString() on the object it crashes. I need to use this output somehow.

```
05-21 12:59:44.586: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(6415): Out of memory on a 847610-byte allocation.
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/dalvikvm(6415): Out of memory: Heap Size=15559KB, Allocated=12932KB, Bitmap Size=613KB
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
05-21 12:59:44.636: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6415):     at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:384)
```

I need step by step guide how to increase the heap for and Android application. I don't run the command line.

Comment: Why do you need to create such a large string? Can't you iterate through the collection "manually"?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's part of a generation system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that there is a hard limit of 16 MB heap space on Android apps that can only be worked around by [altering the Android source](http://tordtech.blogspot.com/2009/09/memory-limit-on-android.html). Your program has hit this limit: "Out of memory: Heap Size=15559KB". You'll need to figure out how to reduce your program's memory usage. A nice guide to doing this is [here](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/attacking-memory-problems-on-android.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output a string with that size try to write it into a file on the SD-Card. That is the only way I can think of to get this string out of your app. If you append the items one by one to the file you want need that much memory.