# Android - out of memory error -String Builder enlarge buffer

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I’m getting the following error :

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
in java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
... 4 more
```

This appears in following lines:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928557/outofmemoryerror-at-abstractstringbuilder-enlargebuffer

Comment: this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881139/outofmemoryerror-what-to-increase-and-how